# Passing URL query Variable to different Forms

Tags: php, get

I need to send users from a php form to another, but I need to pass a URL query across too. So they are arriving at example.com/Form1.php$email=Whatever@Whatever.com, then they need to passed to example.com/Form2.php$email=Whatever@whatever.com. I can not get it to use $_GET in the '' around the header('Location: http://www.example.com');

See Code

---

```
<?php

$email = $_GET["email"];

$_POST['customerSatisfaction'];
    $to = "blah";
    $email_from = 'blah';
    $email_subject = "blah";
    $headers = "From: $email_from \r\n";
    $email_body =   "   <?xml version = \"1.0\"?>
    <?adf version = \"1.0\"?>
        <adf>

            <prospect>
                <customer>

                <email preferredcontact=\"1\">$email</email>

                </customer>

            </prospect>
        </adf>
";
    mail($to,$email_subject,$email_body,$headers);
    header('Location: http://www.BLAH.com/NEED $EMAIL HERE!!');
?>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What you posted is invalid. Try this:

`header('Location: http://www.BLAH.com/?email=' . urlencode($email));`

Also it's usually a good idea to add `exit;` after sending a redirect header.

Comment: How do I avoid getting ?email=Blah%40Gmail.com?

I can't parse on the receiving end.

Comment: The `@` has been encoded because it is a special character. $_GET will decode it automatically, you don't have to do anything.

Comment: But on the other side it isnt, the parse is taking it down with %40.

I know you use urldecode with $_GET but I dont see where.

Comment: $_GET automatically passes variables through urldecode. Do not do it manually, as I said you don't have to do anything! See the warning here http://php.net/manual/en/function.urldecode.php